# Query mysql to get data based on some characters from the contents of a column?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to do a query on a MySQL database to get data from a column based on some characters from that column. For example in the name column, there are many names, I want to get data with names starting with 'AN' or 'AB'. Hope someone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Like Operator is used to perform this operation**
Query: Select *  from table-name where name like 'AN%'

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could show some examples of what you have and what you want as your result.

A simple `LIKE` should work for you with a `%` wildcard at the end.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
table_name t
where t.<name_column> like 'AN%' OR t.<name_column> like 'AB%'
```

Did you try this?